# Float image to right in an anchor in a list

Tags: html, css

Trying to get my arrow image to stick to the right of the anchor

```
<ul>
   <li><a class="linkchild" href="#"><img class = "arrow" src="Images/arrow.png" alt="&#9658;"> 3.1 jQuery</a> 
    <ul>
        <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">3.1.1 Download</a></li>
        <li><a class="linkchild" href="#">3.1.2 Tutorial</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a  class="linkchild" href="#">3.2 Mootools</a></li>
   <li><a class="linkchild" href ="#">3.3 Prototype</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
img .arrow 
{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: what is your problem? I can't see a question anywhere...

Comment: there is a space between img & .arrow in css. It should be like img.arrow.

Comment: NExt question how do vertically align the image with the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
img .arrow
```

-> a child of an image tag with the class `arrow` - your current css

```
img.arrow
```

-> an image with the class `arrow` - probably what you really wanted to write

Comment: This is already written in comment. No use of making these simple things as answers just to earn points.

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used as like this

```
img.arrow 
{
    float: right;
}
```

**not this**

```
img .arrow 
{
    float: right;
}
```

Because you used

```
<img src="" class="arrow">
```

Comment: This is already written in comment. No use of making these simple things as answers just to earn points.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this layout:

```
3.1 jQuery [IMG]
3.1.1 Tutorial
....
```

You could `float:left` the anchor tags to shrink-wrap to their content, including the `float:right`-ed image:

http://jsfiddle.net/4REuw/

```
img.arrow {
    float: right;
}

a {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
​
```